# where is the created plugin (gtk) file?

Tags: dm-script

I use the following script to create the plugin (`gtk`), but after I run the script, I do not know where is the created plugin (`gtk`) file? 
I checked the folder

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Gatan\DigitalMicrograph\PlugIns

I do not know see any new created `gtk` file in the folder.

Is this script wrong or the created `gtk` file should be in somewhere else?

```
/ Define the necessary variables string base,menu,submenu,item,packageNAME,name
number maxitem,i,j,maxfolder taggroup tgFILES,tgFOLDERS,tg

// Just some starting text in the results window.
result("\n Automatic Installation of all scripts in a folder as Plugin:\n\n")

// First get the default folder. (In this case, the folder last opened within DM)
base = GetApplicationDirectory(2,0)

// Prompt the user with a dialog to choose a folder, with the default folder as first choice.

// If the user cancels the dialog, the script will stop.
If (!GetDirectoryDialog("Please select the folder containing the scripts",base,base)) exit(0)

// Ask the user for a package name

If (!GetString("Name of package file?","",packageNAME)) exit(0)

// Ask the user for a menu name

If (!GetString("Name of menu to install the scripts in","",menu)) exit(0)

// Get all files/folders in the folder as a tag-list
tgFILES = GetFilesInDirectory(base,1)
tgFOLDERS = GetFilesInDirectory(base,2)

// Install all files from the main folder as menu commands.

// Count Items in the folder
maxitem = tgFILES.TagGroupCountTags()
i = 0

// Loop through all items
while (i<maxitem)
 {

// get taggroup of item
 tgFiles.TagGroupGetIndexedTagAsTagGroup(i,tg)

 // get name of file
 tg.TagGroupGetTagAsString("Name",item)

 // Only if filename end with ".s" continue
 If (right(item,2)==".s")
 {

 // use the name without the ending
 name = left(item,len(item)-2)
 result("\n Installing: "+item)

 // install the menu command

 // use the Try-Catch loop to detect problems during install
 try
 { AddScriptToPackage(base+item,packageNAME,0,name,menu,"", 0) }
 catch
 { result(" \t ERROR DURING INSTALL") } }
 i++ }

// Now install all files from sub-folder as sub-menu commands.

// Count subfolders in the folder

maxfolder = tgFOLDERS.TagGroupCountTags()

// Loop for all subfolders
for (j=0;j<maxfolder;j++) 

 {
 // get taggroup of item
 tgFolders.TagGroupGetIndexedTagAsTagGroup(j,tg)

 // get name of subfolder which is also the name of the submenu
 tg.TagGroupGetTagAsString("Name",submenu)

// Get all files in the subfolder as a tag-list
 tgFILES = GetFilesInDirectory(base+submenu,1)

 // Count Items in the folder
 maxitem = tgFILES.TagGroupCountTags()
 i = 0

 // Loop through all items as before for the main folder
 while (i<maxitem)
 {
 tgFiles.TagGroupGetIndexedTagAsTagGroup(i,tg)
 tg.TagGroupGetTagAsString("Name",item)
 If (right(item,2)==".s")
 {
 name = left(item,len(item)-2)
 result("\n Installing <"+submenu+">: "+item)
 try {
 AddScriptToPackage(base+item,packageNAME,0,name,menu,submenu, 0) }
 catch
 {
 result(" \t ERROR DURING INSTALL") } }
 i++ } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably running into the "Compatibility files" feature of Windows 7.  GMS 1.x has only one variant of the `AddScriptFileToPackage` function and it always wants to save the resulting package file to the standard DM PlugIns folder:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Gatan\DigitalMicrograph\Plugins
```

But in Windows 7, such direct writing of files to subfolders of the Program Files directory is prevented and files are instead written to a user-specific local directory named as follows:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Gatan\DigitalMicrograph\Plugins
```

However, one can easily make such virtualized files visible by clicking on the "Compatibility files" button that appears in the tool bar of the Windows explorer window for the standard PlugIns folder.

Comment: Thanks for digging out the old GMS 1.x behaviour. Never had that in combination with win7. I've never seen a "Compatibility files" button in the Windows explorer neither! I'll have to look out for one the next time.

Answer (score 1):

This depends a little on the GMS version and the OS version you're running on. I assume you're using GMS 2.x on a Windows7 or Windows8 machine, then the command `AddScriptFileToPackage` can have two syntax versions:

`void AddScriptFileToPackage( String file_path, String packageName, Number packageLevel, String packageLocation, String command_name, String menu_name, String sub_menu_name, Boolean isLibrary )`

`void AddScriptFileToPackage( String file_path, String packageName, Number packageLevel, String command_name, String menu_name, String sub_menu_name, Boolean isLibrary )`

in the first version *packageLocation* could be **user_plugin** or **plugin**. If this parameter is omitted (2nd command version) then *user_plugin* is assumed.

For **user_plugin** you will find the created file in:
`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Gatan\Plugins` 
where USERNAME is the current windows user.

For **plugin** you will find the created file in the 'plugins' subfolder relative to the installation of the 'DigitalMicograph.exe', most likely in:
`C:\Program Files\Gatan\Plugins`

Comment: I use GMS 1.84. 1282 in WIN 7,  there is a  Plugins folder in the C:\Program Files\Gatan\Plugins .   But I would like to know where is the created gtk file. Thanks

Comment: You may miss what I am asking.  I try to combine few scripts to a gtk file. But after I use the code I provided in my original question, I do not know where is the created gtk file.   I know where is the plugins folder, but there is no created  gtk file (I named it) in the plugins folder.

Comment: @together: No, I've understood you well. Depending on the parameter, it is in either of the two locations I've mentioned. Most likely, you'll find it in the "windows-user" specific application folder. The first of the two above. the folder might be "hidden" depending on your windows settings. Oh, and the file is only created if the installed scripts existed and where installed correctly.

Comment: @together: Do your scripts actually get installed in the menu and sub-menus that you expect?  If not, then the problem is with the script file access, as briefly mentioned at the end of the comment by BmyGuest.  You do not mention whether your scripts actually get loaded into the menu.  By the way, by specifying a packageLevel value of 0, the package file will actually have a file type extension of .gt1 (not .gtk).

Comment: Hi Mike and Bmyguest,  Thanks a lot for both your answer.   I checked the installed scripts with my DM, There is menu and submenu that I expect with my DM software, but the script command can not run. After I clicked it, it pop up a message"  Error in line 1, syntax error" , I think this is the reason why I could not find the created gtk file. How to fix this? I will spend some time on the codes itself to see what is wrong with it.

Comment: @together: If you have the expected menus and submenus, then your script installation worked and your package file was definitely created somewhere, almost certainly in the "Compatibility files" folder mentioned in the answer I posted.  The fact that clicking on your menu gives an error means that the script you installed for that menu item has a bug in it.  It will be most efficient to test each of your scripts by opening, executing, and debugging each one from a script window first before you bundle them into a package of menu items with your installer script.

Comment: Hi Mike,  Thanks a lot, I got the original script from the following link, http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEYQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fportal.tugraz.at%2Fportal%2Fpage%2Fportal%2FFiles%2Ffelmi%2Fimages%2FDM-Script%2FHow_to_organize_DM_scripts.pdf&ei=r_x4U3XL66AEz_GAgA0&usg=AFQjCNFy0OMks-dSEIquptHPSElzlpWATg&sig2=mxmbN9oKbNT5tWm0kB-sNw&bvm=bv.66917471,d.cGU&cad=rja , I will check the code in detail